# Looping over a Bash array: getting the next element in the middle of the loop

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, element

Searching an array (lines_ary[@]) which has read a file into it, I'm trying to find a version number in the text. Here I am looking for Release, so I can find the version number that follows.

Is there any way to access the next element in an array in a bash script when doing the following loop?

```
for i in ${lines_ary[@]}; do
 if [ $i == "Release:" ] ; then
  echo ${i+1}
 fi
done
```

This just prints out '1', rather than say '4.4'.

Comment: Just FYI `${i+1}` says to print the value of `$i` if `i` is unset (i.e., print an empty string), but print the word following the plus sign (in this case, "1") otherwise. The plus sign is the Use Alternate Value operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the lines array looks something like

```
array=("line 1" "Release: 4.4" "line 3")
```

Then you can do:

```
# loop over the array indices
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
    if [[ ${array[i]} =~ Release:\ (.+) ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"   # the text in the capturing parentheses
        break
    fi
done
```

output:

```
4.4
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to loop on an *index* over the array rather than the elements of the array itself:

```
for ((index=0; index < ${#lines_ary[@]}; index++)); do
  if [ "${lines_ary[index]}" == "Release:" ]; then
    echo "${lines_ary[index+1]}"
  fi
done
```

Using `for x in ${array[@]}` loops over the elements rather than an index over it. Use of the variable name `i` is not such a good idea because `i` is commonly used for indexes.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. the line contains both "Release:" + "4.4", so they are considered one element in this code. Any thoughts?

Comment: This causes out of bounds error as the array is indexed from 0, not 1. So if array's size is 6, the last element is array[5]. You can check for yourself, just `set -eu`, and Bash throws an `unbound variable` error. You need `<` instead of `<=` in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
for ((index=0; index < ${#lines_ary[@]}; index++)); do
  line=${lines_ary[index]}
  if [[ ${line} =~ ^.*Release:.*$ ]]; then
    release=${line#*Release: *}
  fi
done
```